# Jenkins pipeline from scm with base clearcase

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to set up a Jenkins Pipeline from SCM (base clearcase / existing dynamic view). When i try to apply the changes to the Pipeline an exception is thrown.

Does anyone use base clearcase and Pipeline from SCM with dynamic views?
Perhaps i only have misconfigured the settings for base clearcase and dynamic views.

These are my Settings:

```
View tag: view_name
View path: view_name
config Spec: element * CHECKEDOUT 
include some_file
element * -None
Get load rules from config spec: checked
Use dynamic view: checked
View root: x:\
Do not reset Config Spec: checked
Script path: \Path\to\script_in_view
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using ClearCase at the company and are facing the same problem. I created an incident at Jenkins JIRA, but I don´t think that this will be fixed soon. See

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32551

What we did to finally get the pipleline code in ClearCase:

- Start a job (using "build job" functionality in the pipeline code)
  which puts the code into artifactory
- Use the artifactory functionality of the Pipeline plugin to get the code back again

Before we did this, I tried to set up a perl script which updates the ClearCase view, but it was not stable enough, one of ten times failed. So we use the normal Jenkins ClearCase Plugin by calling a Jenkins job.

In your case, I would recommend following:

- Set up a job which updates your ClearCase view
- In this job, copy the pipeline code to a file server
- Then, after the job is finished, you can load the pipeline code from the file server

The only disadvantage is that you need a real machine which executes the job, but normally, this does not take a lot of time.