# Groovy Script that Writes into a Config File via Linux (for Pipeline)

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, clearcase

I am trying to write a groovy script that will write into a config file on a linux server, how would I set up the groovy script? For example, change some of the values into the config file and save. I have the path and file already defined in the script.

Answer (score 0):

There was attempts to use ClearCase views with Jenkins pipeline before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143445/6309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43539650/6309)), but not with great result.

If you put ClearCase aside, you would need a job executed on the right server, meaning that server is declared as an agent.
Or you would need SSH access from where job is exusted (either the main controller or one of the agents).